# Why doesn't bind(this) apply to an abstracted call to a function as a parameter?

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, this, bind

I am trying to create a sort of dispatcher by passing a general function the can be one of multiple functions that take the same parameters. When I bind `this` it never seems to get bound, but instead `this` is always the global object. Here is an example

```js
class Tester {
 constructor(x){
  this.num = x;
 }

 printer(text){
  console.log(text + this.num);
 }
 generalPrinter(f){
  f("number is: ").bind(this)
 }
}

let t = new Tester(6);
t.generalPrinter(t.printer);
```

In this example I am passing `printer` to `generalPrinter` but might also want to pass a different function that behaves similarly to `printer`.

Comment: This should throw an error. You are calling `.bind` on the *return value* of `f` (`f("number is: ")` calls the function). You want `f.call(this, "number is: ")` instead.

Comment: You're right, that might be the only issue. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Felix's comment:

> This should throw an error. You are calling .bind on the return value of f.

You *probably* don't want to use `bind` like this. `bind` will create a new function object on each invocation. You *probably* want to use `apply` instead:

```
class Tester {
    constructor(x){
        this.num = x;
    }

    printer(text){
        console.log(text + this.x);
    }
    generalPrinter(f, ...args){
        f.apply(this, ["number is: ", ...args])
    }
}

const t = new Tester(6);
t.generalPrinter(t.printer);
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like `apply` and `call` make sense here. When would it make sense to use bind?

Comment: `bind` is useful when you need to pass the this-bound function around and you don't want the `this` to be overwritten. A function that has the context (`this`) defined by `bind` cannot have it overridden... i.e, `function p() { console.log(this) }; p.bind(2).bind(3)()` would print `2`, not `3`

Comment: @JonathanWexler: This may help: https://twitter.com/fkling42/status/736228742008176640